# Deleting all but the most recent Time Machine backup

Tags: time-machine, backup, migration

I just bought a new Mac and I'm manually migrating everything over given that it's been a while since I did a clean install and that the new Mac has less storage than my existing one. I will be wiping the old Mac after I do the migration.

However, I have about 600GB worth of Time Machine backups for the old Mac on the NAS which I'd like to shrink to make space for Time Machine on the new Mac. I just want the latest Time Machine backup to serve as an archive in case I forget to move some files when I wipe the old Mac.

Is it possible to (easily) delete all but the latest snapshot of the Time Machine backup?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assuming OSX 10.8 or later, you could use a combination of **find** and **tmutil**

`tmutil delete <path>` will remove the snapshot at `<path>`

while

`find /path/to/backups/ -maxdepth 1`
will list all of your backup snapshots.  The last one ( **Latest** ) is a link to the latest one.  You can be a little creative and use `find /path/to/backups -name 2\* -maxdepth 1` to list only the "real" directories (all the dates which start with 2014, etc).  And, finally, (thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127726/getting-head-to-display-all-but-the-last-line-of-a-file-command-substitution-an)) you can get a list of all but the last snapshot:

```
find /path/to/backups -name 2\* -maxdepth 1 | sed \$d
```

Comment: It might be easier to use `tmutil listbackups` to get a list of all snapshots (which then can get passed to `tmutil delete` directly)

Comment: Good point-- I'll update the answer. Forgot about the listbackups command.

Comment: But wait -- doesn't listbackups only work for the current machine and not another machines snapshots?

Comment: Ah, maybe, can't try that though.

Comment: I just set up a test here, and sure enough it only shows the current computer's snapshots.  `tmutil help listbackups` outputs "Print paths to all of **this computer's** completed backups" (emphasis added).  So, even though the find/sed flow is contrived, it may be the easiest way to do what the OP wants.